# Tesseract OCR: image to text containing 2 columns of text

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have an article in PNG format with 2 columns of text that I'm trying to read using Python and Tesseract OCR. However, by default, Tesseract reads from left to right in a horizontal wa. Is there an option to automatically detect the columns in the text and read from left to right column by column?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know your only chance is that one of the page segment mode available will work with your image

docs here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage#using-different-page-segmentation-modes